# Interception of aggregation functions in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I want to store encrypted data in database. But I want to be able to correctly execute the SUM(), AVG() and others. Can I somehow intercept them on Cassandra server side and perform the actions I need?

Answer (score 0):

These aggregation functions are built-in into Cassandra, and you can't intercept them until you modify the source code, and deploy modified version of Cassandra. But you can provide your own implementations, and instruct people to use them instead of using built-in.